# PHP command to return stack of functions

Tags: php, debugging

I've used it before, but today, after several failed searches I've been unable to find what I'm looking for.

A PHP command that will return the name of the calling function, and the function that called it, 5 levels or so deep.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ```$e = new \Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for debug_print_backtrace.
From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php):

> debug_print_backtrace() prints a PHP backtrace. It prints the function calls,
> included/required files and eval()ed stuff.

If, however, you want the data not printed immediately but returned you could use debug_backtrace(), save it to a var and only use the ['function'] index.
Of course this function also is better described in [its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

If you want the stack trace after you caught an exception via try catch for example, you could also use this:

```php
try {
    // stuff
} catch(\Exception $e){
     $stackTrace = $e->getTraceAsString();
     // do whatever you want to with your stack trace
}
```

You can also just create a new Exception using

```
$e = new \Exception;
```

And get the stack trace via

```
$e->getTraceAsString();
```

That function is also explained further in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/exception.gettraceasstring.php).